# fetch cookie value of a website from safari browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I want to create a browser extension for a webpage of ours in safari I am having a javascript code snippet which fetches cookie value of a particular website using "chrome.cookies.getAll"
i want to have the safari alternative for chrome.cookies.getAll
is there any viable options available?

Comment: What's wrong with `document.cookie`?

Comment: for extensions we use API like chrome.cookies.getAll for chrome browser and browser.cookies.getAll for firefox i want to know whether there is any API like that for safari.
i want to create browser extension using safari.
my key necessity is to fetch the cookie of a specific website from the browser using javascript from extension.
document.cookie works but not the way i want

Comment: @AbdulRahimA, Firefox works just fine with `chrome.cookies.getAll`, you do not need to use the `browser.*` namespace unless you want to use Promises and *not* be compatible with Chrome. In other words, for most things, using the `chrome.*` APIs your code can be compatible with both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Makyen cool...i was going to change my code for making the extension compatiable with firefox, anyways thank you for the info, i want to know whether there is any alternative for chrome.cookies.getAll in safari browser.